# Vega lite/Altair parsing date specified in quarters

Tags: vega, vega-lite, altair

I have a dataset with data in the form 2000Q1, 2000Q2 etc.  I would like to use this as a temporal variable.

How can I achieve this in Vega Lite/Altair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [timeParse](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/#timeParse) in combination with [string functions](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/#string-functions)  as part of a [calculate transform](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/calculate.html).

timeParse uses [d3 time formats](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/), which unfortunately don't support quarters natively, so we need to do some string manipulations.

It's not very elegant, but here's the Vega Lite

```
"transform": [
    {
      "as": "date",
      "calculate": "timeParse(replace(replace(replace(replace(datum.yearquarter, 'Q1', '02'), 'Q2', '05'),  'Q3', '08'), 'Q4', '11'), '%Y%m')"
    }
  ]
```

In Altair, this looks like this:

```
chart = alt.Chart(url
).transform_calculate(date = "timeParse(replace(replace(replace(replace(datum.yearquarter, 'Q1', '02'), 'Q2', '05'),  'Q3', '08'), 'Q4', '11'), '%Y%m')"
).mark_bar().encode(
y = 'sum(value):Q',
x = 'date:T'
)
```